# Map is not load: uncaught referenceerror google is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've been stuck here all around. This is my code. Somebody please help me. Im using Joomla 3 for my web page and looking for this solution.
    Thanks in advance.

```
<p> </p>
<h3><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Address</span></h3>
<p>Jalan Bangsar, Federal Hill, 50590 Kuala Lumpur, Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur<br />    Tel: +603-2297-9400<br />    Fax: +603-2282-3114<br />    <a href="mailto:webmaster.iku@moh.gov.my">webmaster.iku@moh.gov.my</a><br />    <a href="http://www.iku.gov.my">http://www.iku.gov.my/</a></p>
<h3 style="line-height: 24px;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Map Barcode Scan</span></h3>
<p><img src="images/QRickit.png" alt="" width="289" height="289" /></p>
<script>// <![CDATA[
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(3.1303, 101.68059);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID //ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID, or TERRAIN
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Institute of Public Health'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); ]]>
// ]]></script>
<h3 style="line-height: 24px;"> </h3>
<p> </p>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add `<script>` tag to load google maps script.

Comment: @Styx thanks. actually im noob about this coding and i just continued others work. So, where should i put the <script>,

Comment: Just follow this guide: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map